# for loop iterating over files in directory - skipping files

Tags: bash, for-loop

I'm trying to iterate over files in a directory. The directory contains files

```
{3-23*01.fastq, 3-23D*01.fastq,3-23*02.fastq,3-23*03.fastq,3-23*04.fastq,3-23D*01.fastq,3-30*01.fastq 3-30-3*01.fastq,3-30*02.fastq,3-30-3*02.fastq,3-30*03.fastq,3-30-3*03.fastq}
```

For some reason, though, when I iterate over the files, like I do in the for loop below, it skips some files? Or thinks two files are actually one? I'm not really sure what's going on.

```
for PATH_TO_FILE in *; do
echo $PATH_TO_FILE
echo "hello"
done
```

Output:

```
3-23*01.fastq 3-23D*01.fastq
hello
3-23*02.fastq
hello
3-23*03.fastq
hello
3-23*04.fastq
hello
3-23D*01.fastq
hello
3-30*01.fastq 3-30-3*01.fastq
hello
3-30*02.fastq 3-30-3*02.fastq
hello
3-30*03.fastq 3-30-3*03.fastq
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `ls -1` in that directory ?

Comment: Don't use `PATH` as your own variable name! This is a critical system variable for finding programs, and overwriting it will only end in tears.  That's not the cause of your problem, but it will be once you fix your quoting.

Comment: Use lowercase variables.

Comment: Ah, so I didn't exactly use the variable $PATH. I used $PAIRED_TO_PAIRED_END_FILE so I thought I would just simplify without realizing that new problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quote the variable when printing to avoid filenames being for the `*` in the filename:

```
for PATH in *; do
  echo "$PATH"
  echo "hello"
done
```

`PATH` is probably not the right variable name as you'll loose your shell's `PATH`.

Comment: `echo` handles multiple arguments pretty much the same as a single quoted one, so I don't see how this could help. Good point about the `PATH` variable name, though.

Comment: @CostiCiudatu It's the shell that expands the filenames here. `echo a*b` is not same as `echo "a*b"`. So it will definitely help.

Comment: I see... It's a subtle "double expansion". You may be right! I have to test it. You have my vote, anyway.

Comment: Thanks! This worked, but I don't fully understand why. Why is it only some files that get grouped together and not expanded?

Comment: @jyu429 When shell expands `a*b` for example, it'll include all files that match this pattern: `adb`, `ahelllwolrdb`,`ab` etc. Look at the lines where it has multiple file names in your question and you'll see the pattern and why they are grouped.

Comment: BTW, the POSIX standard actually suggests using lower-case names for just this reason (to avoid overriding system variables); thus, `for path in *` would be the better-practice alternative. See fourth paragraph of http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html